# How to Disable Images in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a set if images in a row. There is a text box input above these images and based on the input i need to enable/disable images?
How to do this in React.

I tried adding "disable" to image tag and disabled=true but both didn't work.

```
const IBox = props => 
  <div  style={props.styles.imageContainer} >
    <img id="image1" src={require('../../../public/images/image1.jpg')} alt = "Image1" /><span >&nbsp;</span>
    <img id="image2" src={require('../../../public/images/image2.jpg')} alt ="Image2" /><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <img id="image3" src={require('../../../public/images/image3.jpg')} alt ="Image3" /><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <img id="image4" src={require('../../../public/images/image4.jpg')} alt ="Image4"/>
  </div>
export default IBox;
```

Comment: What should happen if you disable the images? Should they disappear? Are show something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "enable/disable images"? please explain more, also there's no div tag in react-native

Comment: @VincentRolea I just need to know how to disable these images..I have an input box on state change of that input i will disable these images...

Comment: What is "disabling" an image to you? I can see what disabling an input should do, but not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "disabling" images. You can only disable form elements, as they are the only interactive html elements. See w3c [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/disabled-elements.html) to see which items can be disabled exactly.

That is unless you write your own custom definition for disabling images. For example, you could add a class `disabled` to the image, and style that class to be greyed out, using CSS.

You could also combine CSS with [WebComponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) to have an element that with a disabled attribute. You could style its disabled style.

See also [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) for the `<img />` tag.

Comment: suppose if I wrap each image inside a span tag , will I be able to disable that?

Comment: @JokerBean you can, but a span also does not have the capability to be disabled. Could you elaborate on what you expect the "disabled" state to do for the img-element?

Comment: @Webber like making the  opacity of the image to 0

Comment: @JokerBean, so that's one use case of what I have already described in my answer; give the image a className of `disabled` based on some condition, and then style that `img.disabled` with the styles you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean hide/show.. you simply may use state to disable your image i.e.

```
{this.state.img1 && <img id="image1" src={require('../../../public/images/image1.jpg')} alt = "Image1" />}
```

if by disable you mean to make it like grey, low opacity,etc... you may use an state :

style= this.state.disable? {{style_disable}}: {{style_enable}}

Comment: OP never asked for hiding images. This answer is based on big assumptions. Although popular in votes and a common thing to do in react, it's still not a correct answer.

Comment: @Webber what you say is not necessarily correct  since part of an answer, when somebody asks, is to help him to understand what he really needs. So, we are not putting things to earn votes, we try to help someone to cope with the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input />` instead of `<img />` as in this example.
You can provide the same functionality with the `type="image"` attribute. This way you can use the `disabled` attribute.

```
<input
  type="image"
  disabled={disabled}
/>
```